# LiteSpeed cache Plugin showing HTML only at the start

Tags: mobile, memcached, usability, litespeed

I am facing a problem. I have used the LiteSpeed cache plugin and it did reduce the page load time but its largest content paint is in link which is causing "clickable elements too close together" problem in Google usability.

When I type the URL in incognito window, it show the links only without any CSS/JS. It looks like a word doc with a lot of hyper links.

Please also see the attached screenshot of how the website shows.
https://ibb.co/DKCHVfZ

In short, it seems like basic HTML and that is what causing issues in Google Mobile usability problem.

There was no problem about the mobile usability first but the speed was low. LiteSpeed has solved the loading time problem but now, I need to solve mobile usability problem.

I will highly appreciate all the help I can get.

Best Regards

Dawood Ahmad

Comment: Where's the screenshot? If you have Guest mode enabled, try to disable it and see if it helps.

Comment: Please check the screenshot here. https://ibb.co/DKCHVfZ

Comment: Two possible reasons, one is the guest mode, and another one is JS/CSS optimization. You can try to disable those features + purge all, and see if it fixed the issue.